# How does the independence of $U$ and $V$ guarantee $\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{U}{V} \right) = \mathbb{E}(U) \cdot \mathbb{E}\left( \frac 1{V} \right)$?

Tags: statistics

I saw in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1087110/654677) the following claim (constants omitted):

> Where U and V are random, independent variables,
>   $$\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{U}{V} \right) = \mathbb{E}(U) \cdot \mathbb{E}\left( \frac 1{V} \right)$$

Distributing the expected value operator through in this way seems wrong to me. "Multiplication by two" is a linear operator, but 
$$2\left( \frac{U}{V} \right) = \frac{2U}{V}\qquad\neq\qquad 2(U) \cdot 2\left( \frac 1{V} \right) = \frac{4U}{V} $$

If we can't distribute the linear operator across division

$$\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{U}{V} \right) \neq \frac{\mathbb{E}(U)}{\mathbb{E}(V)}$$

then why can we distribute it across multiplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with linearity and everything to do with independence. (Just because we can't apply linear operators in such a way in general doesn't mean that there isn't *some* linear operator in *some* situation that this rule applies to.) For instance, if the distributions are continuous $f_U$ and $f_V$ are the pdfs, we have $$ E(U/V) = \int (u/v) f_U(u)f_V(v) du dv =\left(\int uf_U(u)du\right)\left(\int (1/v)f_V(v)dv\right)=E(U)E(1/V).$$ It's just because the joint distribution factors as $f_{U,V}(u,v) = f_U(u)f_V(v)$.

Comment: Well, that was obvious in hindsight. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If $U$ and $V$ are independent random variables, then
$$\mathbb{E}[f(U) g(V)] = \mathbb{E}[f(U)] \mathbb{E}[g(V)]$$
for any reasonable functions $f$ and $g$. In particular, $\mathbb{E}[U/V] = \mathbb{E}[U] \mathbb{E}[1/V]$. These equalities do not hold in general (without the independence assumption).